# hasClass addClass updates based on hashtag update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a snag on a simple `.hasClass` `.addClass` concept. I have a full page layout that matches my media devices viewport. When you scroll or click on the nav it jumps to the next corresponding div by way of the transference of a `active` class.

What I'm hoping to do is `addClass` to the `active` divs img inside it to apply an animation into the page. For some reason though, this is just not working out for me. As the `active` class transfers the img doesn't update with it.

Thoughts?

```js
  if ( $('.section').hasClass('active') ) {
    $('.active img').addClass('slideUp');
  }
```

```css
.section { min-height: 200px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.15); padding: 15px; }
.active img { background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section active" id="section0">
  <img src="http://www.smashbros.com/images/character/kirby/main.png">
 </div>
 
  <div class="section" id="section1">
  <img src="https://kirby.nintendo.com/planet-robobot/assets/img/home/copy-kirby.png">
 </div>
```

Comment: It is very difficult to understand your problem. Can you add jsfiddle with explanations?

Comment: when is the `hasClass` check being run? all of this code looks fine so it's almost certain that the issue is you're checking `hasClass` in the wrong place

Comment: Your code is adding the `slideUp` class, as programmed. You have no definition of `.slideUp` in your CSS, so it doesn't do much, but it's doing what it was told to do...

Comment: where is the slideUp css? If there are no styles defined, it will add the class but that class won't do anything.

Comment: Do you mean `.slideUp()`?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I'd purposefully left out the `slideUp` CSS animation due to the actual animation wasn't the point of focus. @Pabs123 I think has hit on the issue though. @Pabs123 it currently `$(document).ready(function() {` so you're probably right. It's running only once at document ready. Is there a way to have the script constantly monitor for the change so that it can update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comment, just add the slideUp class at the same time as you add the active class (basically on the click listener for the nav)

Comment: Good call on this @Pabs123. I found my answer in a function getSlideByAnchor(slideAnchor, section)